# Which kind of evil will I should assign to an immortal character?

Tags: dnd-5e, npc, story, wish

I've been playing a D&D campaign with some friends for a while, we made 4 sessions already and between these sessions, there's strange man who appears to aid or guide them towards an objective.

This guy started in the campaign since the first episode, started as a mysterious hooded figure, which was discovered by them to have his own tavern and also has knowledge with chemicals, which he used in one combat. He also told the group about a medallion that can grant one wish, but it will only do what the heart of the wearer wishes (kinda like the ice king crown on adventure time).

This character in question is immortal, he's a master alchemist, who accidentally made himself immortal when an experiment failed, and after being depressed for so many years working as a tavern owner, he decided to move between kingdoms, trying to find a group fool enough to fall for his plan of collecting the artifact for him, considering that his immortality would easily be discovered if he stood up to act himself.

I've got some plans for the final meeting with the alchemist, where either he and the group have a fight or him managing to steal the medallion from the group and then activating it himself to grant a wish. The problem is this was a character that accidentally showed up as an antagonist, so I'm really lost on what would be his will, his wish when he activates the medallion. Do you guys have any ideas on what could i make as his wish?

PS: This medallion can only be activated in a temple, and will always have a negative effect when activated.

Comment: Hi Henry, welcome to the site, and feel free to take the  [tour] if you have a minute. Unfortunately we don't do this kind of idea generation questions well on this site, where the format is questions that hopefully have a correct or best answer. You might try a forum, instead, we maintain a [list of those](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

Comment: "Accidentally" made himself immortal?

Comment: Now that you have 20 reputation, you can also ask the question in our [chat].